# QMovie doesn't show GIF file in Mac

Tags: qt, macos, qt4.7

In my project, I use QMovie as a loading bar. It works well in Windows. However, I moved my project to Mac and it didn't work anymore.

The GIF image file is in the resource file. I tried using both resource file path and absolute file path. But, it seems not okay.

Thanks

Comment: Movieplayer example is working... So, it should work in my project. I am checking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used QPaintEvent and QRect to show loading animation. Now, the problem was solved by following MoviePlayer example of Qt using QLabel::setMovie function.

Answer (score 0):

Gif capacity is done with a plugin. Your application needs to be able to load qgif4 plugin at runtime to be able to display gif

=> make sure your gif imageformat plugin is compiled, deployed and in your application library path (note that these paths can be checked at runtime using [QCoreApplication::libraryPaths](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qcoreapplication.html#libraryPaths)

Comment: Thanks, the plugins are ok. :D

Comment: Now, it is working... I just follow the MoviePlayer example. 
I used QRect and i drawed the movie frame in the paintEvent.
Now, I just use QLabel and setMovie function. 
Thanks